# Drupal Content Type: how to add a checkbox that hides an object if checked?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a Drupal site and I want to add a checkbox within a content type that will hide an object if checked.

I am not to worried about how to hide it, I can figure that out with Js or CSS later on but I need to know how to add a checkbox that has the ability to modify the display.

I think its going to be along the lines of adding a new field but I don't know what type of field to add.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [drupal: Form API, dynamically hide or show fields based on input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753010/drupal-form-api-dynamically-hide-or-show-fields-based-on-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by adding form alter,

You need to write the form alter then you can add [`states`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#states) property for the field you need to show or hide

```
$form['your_showhide_field']['#states'] = array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="you_checkbox_name"]' => array('checked' => true),
            ),
        );
```

OR

You can also use [field condition state](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state) module to do this.